# How to link library path of the boost library in VS Code?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-code

I have downloaded and built the boost library with the following commands
`bootstrap.bat gcc` and then `b2 toolset=gcc`. After that I've also included it in the compiler path in vs code in `c_cpp_properties.json` .The file is included(I know this as the error in my file that was highlighted before including the path vanished) but I am unable to link the libraries in vs code. While running the code shows the following error:

```
PS E:\VS Code Workspaces\Projects> cd "e:\VS Code Workspaces\Projects\C++ Projects\CodeChef\" ; if ($?) { g++ fctrl.cpp -o fctrl } ; if ($?) { .\fctrl }       
fctrl.cpp:2:9: fatal error: boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include<boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I do have a last option to install the mingw distro from nuwen but I would like to avoid that. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did boost install itself? You should have paths that end in /include and /lib; you'll need to add these both to the build configuration, as 'additional include path' and 'library search path' or similar respectively, and tell it to link the boost library (`-lboost` ?)

Comment: Boost installed itself in the same directory that I extracted it to. I also used the `c++ -I path/to/boost_1_71_0 fctrl.cpp -o fctrl \ -L E:/boost_1_71_0/stage/lib -lboost_system` command to see if it runs but it didn't and I had included the /include path but I cannot find where to put the library path in vs code.

Comment: The -I part should be enough to get past the missing include file at least, though? Can you find cpp_int.hpp in your boost build tree?

Comment: Yeah it's there in the build tree also as I've mentioned vs code can see that the file exists as it has stopped showing me the missing include error. I think the only problem is that I am unable to link the library through it.